# Wrap Python3 program as an app

Tags: automator, high-sierra, python

I have a `Python3` script that I wrote; this uses `tkinter` to bring up a window prompting users to connect to shared resources.

This all works OK, and I normally run it from a terminal.

I want to wrap this in a `.app` so that it appears in Launcher and can be used by others in my family, who are averse to the command line.

In the past I have used an `Automator` Application with `Run Shell Script` selecting shell `/usr/bin/python`, however `macOS` doesn't include `Python3` so I have installed Python 3.6.4 and I can't seem to find a way to run a python3 shell.

I have tried using my normal shell script, commencing:-

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import os
```

This generates a string of errors:-

```
The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “from: can't read /var/mail/tkinter
from: can't read /var/mail/tkinter
-: line 5: import: command not found
```

I have tried a number of other options, including `/usr/bin/env python3`

```
The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “env: python3: No such file or directory
from: can't read /var/mail/tkinter
from: can't read /var/mail/tkinter
/Users/ian/bin/connect.py: line 5: import: command not found
```

and finally got this to work with:-

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3 /Users/ian/bin/connect.py
```

This is rather clumsy and requires the script to be in an external file.

I am looking for a solution, comparable the running python2 script.

I am unsure if this should be asked on this site or Stack Overflow.

Comment: FWIW A common causes of a _shell script_ working okay in **Terminal** but not in a **Run Shell Script** _action_ in **Automator** is a `PATH` issue, because the _value_ of `PATH` usually differs between the two when non-default and or third party programs are involved. The `PATH` passed to a **Run Shell Script** _action_ in **Automator** is `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` yet in **Terminal** the `PATH` on my system includes other directories from the installation of non-default and or third party programs. The use of the _fully qualified pathnames_ can therefore be necessary in **Automator**.

Comment: You may want to use  "[py2app](https://py2app.readthedocs.io)" to generate mac application. You can take a look at [Creating standalone Mac OS X applications with Python and py2app](https://www.metachris.com/2015/11/create-standalone-mac-os-x-applications-with-python-and-py2app/)